# WPF PathGeometry is displaced in DoubleAnimationUsingPath

Tags: c#, wpf, path, pathgeometry, doubleanimation

so i'm new to WPF and haven't the faintest idea why this doesn't work. I wanna do a DoublePathAnimation on a Ellipse. So i used a PathObject to just simple find out which PathGeometry Figures i need.

```
<Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="5">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M 200,100 C 307,180 390, 180 500,190"></PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
 </Path>
```

But now when im using these Figures in my PathAnimation like this:

```
<Storyboard>
    <!-- The X-axis animation -->
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Name="aniX21"
        Storyboard.TargetName="exportTarget21"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
        Source="X"
        Duration="0:0:03"
        RepeatBehavior="Forever"
        AutoReverse="False">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M 200,100 C 307,180 390, 180 500,190"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Name="aniY21"
        Storyboard.TargetName="exportTarget21"
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Y"
        Source="Y"
        Duration="0:0:03"
        RepeatBehavior="Forever"
        AutoReverse="False">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry Figures=" M 200,100 C 307,180 390, 180 500,190" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
```

the Animation works, but only the x-Coordinates are right. The y-Coordinates are totally displaced.

Comment: hehe sry was my first post and code blocks didn't work x)

Comment: Please be precise. Show [a _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably demonstrates the issue. Explain in exact, precise detail what that code example does, and how what it does is different from what you wanted to do. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask